# Constructing triangulations algorithmically

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics

I am developing a Python package for computations in algebraic topology (namely: cohomology and Massey products on manifolds). Basically all the stuff I'm doing requires an explicit triangulation of the manifold $M$ we're working on, by which I mean a simplicial complex $K$ homeomorphic to $M$ with the additional requirement that the individual simplices are embedded (I'm not sure whether it's a standard requirement or not). Now, writing down an explicit triangulation and all the boundary maps is a pain in the ass, already for the torus you have almost too many simplices hanging around. My question is: is there a simple way to generate triangulations for manifolds starting from other data (e.g. a cellular decomposition)?

More precisely, what I would like is:

> Given data which can be easily and systematically written down if we know our manifold, obtain a triangulation (given by an array containing the number of cells in each dimension and the boundary maps given as matrices) in an algorithmic way.

Comment: Potentially a stupid question, but have you poked around [Sage's](http://www.sagemath.org/) documentation? I have no idea if they have what you're looking for, but they do have completely open code, and a bit of code related to manifolds.

Comment: @pjs36 I didn't know about Sage, so thanks for the hint! Unfortunately looking around I could only find a couple of things going more in the direction of tensor calculus on manifolds or stuff about parametrized surface, so it's not so useful for my problem.

Comment: $\Delta$-complex structures can be subdivided into triangulations. More generally see the keyword "Regular CW complex".

Comment: @MikeMiller Ok, thanks, this helps a bit. But still for example if we take the torus I think we need at least 4 cells in dimension 2 (which is better that the - I think - 7 for triangulations). Is it possible to do better than that? I was thinking of something along these lines, but maybe only asking for the interior of the cells to be embedded and allowing a bit of degeneracy for the boundaries...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do much better - might be a little bit unreasonable to ask as much. Regular CW complexes are pretty nice.